# Python print with integer string mix and group matching problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
import string
line = "F1,F2,F3,F6,R1,R3,R341,C1,C10,C2,FL1,FL5"

line_no_digits= re.findall("\D",line)#produce line with refernces F,F,F,F,R,R,R,C,C,C,FL,FL
line_no_digits_string= ''.join(map(str,line_no_digits))
#############################################################
res = line_no_digits_string.split(",")
alpha_char_unique=[]
for i in res:                      #get unique reference prefix
    if i not in alpha_char_unique:
        alpha_char_unique.append(i)
#############################################################
line2 = line.split(",")
preLine = ""
result = ""
for j in alpha_char_unique:
    p = re.compile(j)
    preLine = [s for s in line2 if p.match(s)]
    numbers_only = [int(re.search('\d+', l).group(0)) for l in preLine if re.search('\d+', l) is not None]#pull numbers for matches or prefix, not working correctly
    numbers_only.sort()#sort the numbers to work in code below
    #print(numbers_only)
    c = 0#counter
    result = ""#output result
    current = None
    run = False
    x = len(numbers_only)
    while c < x:#number sorter

        if current == None:
            result += f'{numbers_only[c]}'
        elif numbers_only[c] - current == 1:
            run = True
            if c == len(numbers_only) - 1:
                result += f'-{numbers_only[c]}'
        elif run:
            result += f'-{current},{numbers_only[c]}'
            run = False
        else:
            result += f',{numbers_only[c]}'

        current = numbers_only[c]
        c += 1
    print(result)
```

The result is
1,1-3,5-6
1,3,341
1-2,10
1,5
I would like it to be
F1-F3,F6
R1,R3,R341
C1-C2,C10
FL1,FL5

matching may not be the best for this.  I am looking for suggestions on how to make sure that F1-F3 and FL1,FL5 are not grouped together.  I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it.

```py
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import string
from collections import OrderedDict
line = "F1,F2,F3,F6,R1,R3,R341,C1,C10,C2,FL1,FL5"

result = []
def add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num):
    if last_letters is None:
        return
    if latest_num > starting_num:
        result.append('%s%d-%s%d' % (last_letters,starting_num,last_letters,latest_num))
    else:
        result.append('%s%d' % (last_letters,starting_num))

letter_map = OrderedDict()
for letters,number in re.findall('([A-Z]+)(\\d+)',line):
    number = int(number)
    if not letters in letter_map:
        letter_map[letters] = []
    letter_map[letters].append(number)

last_letters = starting_num = latest_num = None
for letters,numbers in letter_map.items():
    for number in sorted(numbers):
        if last_letters is None:
            last_letters = letters
            starting_num = latest_num = number
        elif letters == last_letters:
            if number == latest_num + 1:
                latest_num = number
            else:
                add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
                starting_num = latest_num = number

        else:
            add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
            last_letters = letters
            starting_num = latest_num = number
add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
final_result = ','.join(result)
print(final_result) #F1-F3,F6,R1,R3,R341,C1-C2,C10,FL1,FL5
```

**Edit:**
For your modified version from your comment, I think you have a couple of typos: "R1,2" should be "R1.2" and "F2.," should be "F2,". Let me know if those are not typos. Assuming they are, the minimal update to get it working is to accept more than just letters as the prefix, but also allow trailing numbers if they end with a dot. Also allow an underscore. The only thing that needs to change is the regular expression in the re.findall line.

````py
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import string
from collections import OrderedDict
line = "F1.1,F1.2,F1.3.F2,F3,F6,R1.1,R1.2,R1.3,R2,R3,R341,C1,C10,C2,FL_1,FL_5"
result = []
def add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num):
    if last_letters is None:
        return
    if latest_num > starting_num:
        result.append('%s%d-%s%d' % (last_letters,starting_num,last_letters,latest_num))
    else:
        result.append('%s%d' % (last_letters,starting_num))

letter_map = OrderedDict()
for letters,number in re.findall('([A-Z]+_{0,1}(?:[0-9]+\\.){0,1})(\\d+)',line):
    number = int(number)
    if not letters in letter_map:
        letter_map[letters] = []
    letter_map[letters].append(number)

last_letters = starting_num = latest_num = None
for letters,numbers in letter_map.items():
    for number in sorted(numbers):
        if last_letters is None:
            last_letters = letters
            starting_num = latest_num = number
        elif letters == last_letters:
            if number == latest_num + 1:
                latest_num = number
            else:
                add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
                starting_num = latest_num = number
        else:
            add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
            last_letters = letters
            starting_num = latest_num = number

add_result(result,last_letters,starting_num,latest_num)
final_result = ','.join(result)
print(final_result) #F1.1-F1.3,F2-F3,F6,R1.1-R1.3,R2-R3,R341,C1-C2,C10,FL_1,FL_5```
````

Comment: Wow! This is impressive.

Comment: Matt I have gotten new challenges.  What if the string input is "F1.1,F1.2,F1.3.F2.,F3,F6,R1.1,R1,2,R1.3,R2,R3,R341,C1,C10,C2,FL_1,FL_5" and I would like to have the output F1.1-F1.3,F2-F3,F6,R1.1-R1.3,R2-R3,R341,C1-C2,C10,FL_1,FL_5.  I have tried to add it but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: @BryanHildreth, I edited the solution to do what I think you want it to do. Take a look.

Comment: Yes the typos were made.  Thank you so much for altering this.